# Prepared statements with union all or single statement

Tags: php, mysql

Which should i use? In second one there is unknown quantity of statements. I know very little about prepared statements. Trying to change my code from simple queries. And i am stuck here, since it seems to me if i use top one, i'll have to make many request and it will be slower.

```
$stmt  = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=?");
```

or

```
$stmt  = $con->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=? UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=? UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=? UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=? UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=? UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=? UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=? AND col2=?
");
```

edit:

My actual code is:

```
foreach ($games as $ob)
{
    $sql.= "SELECT * FROM (SELECT gamesdata.rating, gamesdata.name, games.game, games.game_id FROM gamesdata 
        INNER JOIN login ON gamesdata.user_id=login.user_id 
        INNER JOIN games ON games.game_id=gamesdata.game_id 
        WHERE username='".$user."' AND game='".$ob->game."' AND gamespl>0 ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 5) DUMMY_ALIAS".$i." UNION ALL ";
    $i++;
}
```

Trying to change this to prepared statements.

Comment: It depends on what your business logic is.   The second one does not appear to make a lot of sense.  You are going to have trouble using bind_param(), as you don't know the number of variables

Comment: Why not just use an `OR` in your `WHERE` condition - `WHERE (col1=? AND col2=?) OR (col1=? AND col2=?) OR ...`. Then you have only 1 query.

Comment: Instead of a loop, you could use MySQL's [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) on your `game` column/`$ob->game` values so you only have 1 query

Comment: there is limit 5, so i have to use union all

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up your prepared statement once and run it with each of the changed inputs.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE col1=:user AND col2=:game UNION ALL");

$prepared = array('user' => $user); // user doesn't change
foreach ($games as $ob) { // for each game
   $prepared['game'] = $ob->game; // set this queries game
   $stmt->execute($prepared); // execute with current game
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // iterate over rows
       var_export($row);
   }
}
```